# TouchableOpacity not working when pressed (React-Native)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

I have a TouchableOpacity Component that is not doing anything when it's pressed. I checked for solution and everything is fine for me, I'm correctly importing the component and I didn't specify absolute position.

Note: hp & wp are from a library where wp(100) is 100% of the screens width

Here is my Implementation:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.icon}
        onPress={() => console.log('Dismissed')}
      >
        <SimpleArrowLeft />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Text style={styles.title}>{getMessageByKey('uploadRecipe.selectMedia')}</Text>
    </View>
    .
    .
    .
```

and for the styling:

```
container: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    width: wp(100),
    height: hp(100),
    left: wp(-5),
  },
  header: {
    paddingTop: wp(5),
    height: hp(7),
    width: wp(100),
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // alignItems: 'center',
  },
  icon: {
    height: hp(3.5),
    width: hp(3.5),
  },
```

Comment: give background color to the touchableopacity and check if it getting proper height and width

Comment: Hi @EndLess. I checked it's getting the proper width and height. I checked many solutions and applied them all and still not working

Comment: Can you make and send me a sample example of the above bug?

Comment: Are you importing TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler ? If yes, import directly from react-native package

Comment: @BloodyMonkey No I'm importing from react-native package

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I was using `postion: 'relative'` in the styling of the `TouchableOpacity` in the styling. So the solution was to place the `TouchableOpacity` at the end of the parent View and it's fixed